# GDB Compilation Issue

Tags: gcc, gdb, g++, abi

I have run in an issue with compiling gdb from [source](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/). I am downloading version 8.2.1 but when I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required.
make[1]: *** [configure-gdb] Error 1
```

My operating system is Red Hat 7.6 (Maipo) but i have a compiled from source gcc(that i set as the default one with an alias in bashrc)

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

which gcc
alias gcc='/usr/local/gcc8.2/bin/gcc'
        /usr/local/gcc8.2/bin/gcc
which g++
alias g++='/usr/local/gcc8.2/bin/g++'
        /usr/local/gcc8.2/bin/g++
```

What i have tried/read so far

- Read the [gdb manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/) regarding the configure and instalation part, also various stackoverflow links but nobody seems to have this problem
- Read the README file in the gdb folder/subfolders
- Tried setting the following env options `CXX_FOR_TARGET=/usr/local/gcc8.2/bin/g++` `GCC_FOR_TARGET=/usr/local/gcc8.2/bin/gcc` (not sure if i should replace target with my actual target architecture)
- Looked in the `gdb-8.2.1` folder at the file `config.log` and found these: ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_value=/usr/local/gcc8.2/bin/gcc
  ac_cv_prog_CXX_FOR_TARGET=/usr/local/gcc8.2/bin/g++
  ac_cv_prog_GCC_FOR_TARGET=/usr/local/gcc8.2/bin/gcc

However in the C compiler section of the same config log I have found the following:

```
configure:4284: checking for C compiler version
configure:4293: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I am not sure ifi can use the devtoolset-8 gdb from RedHat because i have compiled gcc with GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 and on RedHat due to a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1546704) this is disabled by default and i am not sure if gdb will be able to manage the different binary interface.

**Short version**: What am I doing wrong that is making the `GDB configure` script not find the correct compiler and how can i fix/workaround this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into your question. I have rolled your edit back. Instead, post your answer as an answer so others can vote on it.

Comment: Understood. thank you. Will post an answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

A C++11-capable compiler for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 is provided as part of [Red Hat Developer Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/).  It happens to include not just GCC 8, but GDB 8.2 as well, so you may not even have to compile it yourself.  The DTS C++ compiler has been built in a special way so that it interoperates with the system C++ runtime.  Unless you have replicated those modifications in your GCC build, it will not be compatible with the rest of the system (and you will have to replace the system libstdc++ library).

The system compiler in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 is based on GCC 4.8.  In that version, C++11 support was still experimental and not enabled by default.  You can try to configure GDB with

```
./configure CXX="g++ -std=gnu+11"
```

but this is not recommended (only the C++98 mode is supported).

The `configure` script does not use shell aliases because those are not inherited by shell scripts invoked from a shell.  You will have to specify the full path to the C++ compiler explicitly (in the `CXX=` argument to configure), or adjust the `PATH` environment variable manually, or use [`scl enable`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/8/html/user_guide/chap-gcc#sect-GCC-C-Compile) to do so in a more polished fashion (for software collections such as Developer Toolset).

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your answer. I had to compile gcc 8.2 from source due to this bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1546704 .I have also recompiled the libstdc++ lib to 6.0.25 but have also left the old one, not to cause any harm. So basically devtoolset supports c++11 and fwd but not the proper ABI and i am interested in that as well. Iif i compile with devltoolset is gdb going to be ok when i load into it binaries with the newer ABI's? I also thought that i have set those variables by what config.log was telling me. Is there any of them that i haven't set?

Comment: GDB and the debugged process do not have to use the same versions of the fundamental run-time libraries, so that's not a reason to recompile it. The proper ABI for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 is what the system compiler and DTS use, and that is not the new ABI (which was still experimental in GCC 4.8). It is unclear why you need the other ABI and which problem you are trying to solve. Maybe you should submit a question for the other problem?

Comment: Great news if GDB compiled with ABI=0 can debug a dwarf with ABI=1 then my problem is solved. As a side note i need the newer ABI for the extra speed (like small string optimization and other stuff) . I will test with the default devtoolset-8 version of gdb and see what happens.